# How to access etag header from response in Cosmos DB post-trigger

Tags: triggers, azure-cosmosdb, etag, cosmosdbtrigger

I am writing a Cosmos DB post-trigger (NOT the Azure Function Trigger kind but the in-server JS one). In this trigger, I need to access the **etag** header generated in the response. The trigger works fine except when I add the following code :

```
    // Retrieve item's new etag from the response
    var newETag = __.response.getValue("etag");
```

This code causes the request to fail with the following exception : "*Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference at getValueInternal*". I checked that the response is not *null* and that the `getValue` function exists and in fact the exception is thrown from within the `getValue` function because the property for **etag** does not exist.

The [doc (found here)](https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/Response.html) however states that:

> getValue(key) → {string} Gets a specified response header value.

And [other doc (found here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-response-headers) also states that:

> The following response headers are common to all responses from the SQL API: ... etag (The etag header [...] has the same value as the _etag property in the response body.)...

Now I also DID confirm that I could indeed access the **etag** from the `__.response.getBody()` but I cannot rely on that option because my requests are made with the `EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false` option in which case the response body is null.

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing or doing wrong here ?

Comment: You need to set EnableContentResponseOnWrite = true if you want to get anything back in the response object.

Comment: @MarkBrown I believe this flag only applies to the body. Because the headers are actually sent back even with EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false... But nevertheless, I tried with EnableContentResponseOnWrite = true and I get the same exception.